# Lodash iterate nested loops

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am trying to iterate through below Collections JSON object. I am trying to find collection elements which have one of the tags from tagArray. Basically this is a filter exercise to have collection elements that have tags as selected from the tagArray.

```
           {
            1: {
                "description": "AAA",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "tag1",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "tag2",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "tag3",
                    },
                ],
                "name": "XYZ",
            },
            2: {
                "description": "BBB",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "tag1",
                    }
                ],
                "name": "CCC",
            },
            3: {
                "description": "xms",
                "tags": [],
                "name": "Huo",
            },
            4: {
                "description": "asd",
                "tags": [],
                "name": "TXS",
            }
         }
```

tagArray looks like this : [ tag1, tag2, ... ]

I have coded it as below using lodash and it works fine. But I am not sure if I can improve this further and how?

```
const filterByTags = (collections, filterTags) =>  {

let filteredCollections = _.pickBy(collections, (collection) => {
                              let collectionWithTag = false;
                              _.map(collection.tags, (collectionTag) => {
                                if (filterTags.indexOf(collectionTag.name) !== -1) {
                                  collectionWithTag = true;
                                  return collectionWithTag;
                                }
                              });
                              return collectionWithTag;
                            });
  return filteredCollections;
};
```

Comment: you're using `_.map` incorrectly. it's still looping after you think you returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't want to use [`pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/#pickBy) but rather `filter` ([Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#filter)/[native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))
- You don't want to use [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/#map) but rather `some` ([Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#some)/[native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))
- You don't want to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) but rather `includes` ([Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#includes)/[native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes))

```
function filterByTags(collections, filterTags) {
    return _.filter(collections, collection => {
        return _.some(collection.tags, collectionTag => {
            return _.includes(filterTags, collectionTag.name);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What if I want to return an object instead of Array. filter method would return an array. Would it be wise to use pickBy in such a case?

Comment: @GauravShah Then `pickBy` might do it, but it would be wise to use an array instead. Don't use objects with integer property names.

Comment: The team is using object instead of array so we can key the list by id. The id is not necessarily integer. Is it justified to use objects here instead of array?

Comment: Yes. It's just not what your original question had :-)

Comment: I was trying to use dummy data here. Thanks for your inputs :-)